# Spark to Synapse "truncate" not working as expected

Tags: pyspark, databricks, truncate, azure-synapse, overwrite

I have a simple requirement to write a dataframe from spark (databricks) to a synapse dedicated pool table and keep refreshing (truncating) it on daily basis without dropping it.

[Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) suggests to use `truncate` with `overwrite` mode but that doesn't seem to be working as expected for me. As i continue to see table creation date getting updated

I am using

```
df.write \
      .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
      .option("url", synapse_jdbc) \
      .option("tempDir", tempDir) \
      .option("useAzureMSI", "true") \
      .option("dbTable", table_name) \
      .mode("overwrite") \
      .option("truncate","true") \
      .save()
```

But there doesn't seem to be any difference whether i use `truncate` or not. Creation date/time of the table in synapse gets updated everytime i execute the above from databricks. Can anyone please help with this, what am i missing?

I already have a workaround which works but seems more like a workaround

```
.option("preActions", "truncate table "+table_name) \
.mode("append") \
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your scenario in my environment and the truncate is not working for me with the synapse connector.

While researching this issue I found that not all Options are supported to synapse connector In the Official [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/external-data/synapse-analytics#--azure-databricks-synapse-connector-options-reference) the provided the list of supported options like `dbTable`, `query`, `user`, `password`, `url`,  `encrypt=true`, `jdbcDriver`, `tempDir`,   `tempCompression`, `forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials`, `useAzureMSI` , `enableServicePrincipalAuth`, etc.

Truncate    ate option is supported to the `jdbc` format nots synapse connector.

When I change the format form `com.databricks.spark.sqldw` to `jdbc` it's working fine now.

**My Code:**

```py
df.write.format("jdbc")
    .option("url",synapse_jdbc)
    .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true")
    .option("dbTable", table_name)
    .option("tempDir", tempdir)
    .option("truncate","true")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .save()
```

**First execution:**

[image]

[image]

**Second execution:**

[image]

[image]

> **conclusion:** For both the time when code is executed table creation time is same means overwrite is not dropping table it is truncating table